# Extracting url value from xml enclosure tag with c#

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, feed

I'm trying to extract value of url which is basically url of an image in enclosure tag something like this:

```
 <enclosure url="http://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/s3cazinnet/2016/06/OZRK_KRAJINA_2016_5525.JPG?mtime=1465158486" length="" type="image/jpeg">
```

I don't want to bother you with whole classes so I will post just parts of code. And this is the part of code where I'm trying to get value of url:

```
if (xmlNode[i].SelectSingleNode("enclosure:url", xmlNameSpaceManager) != null)
{
    var Url = xmlNode[i].Attributes["url"].Value;
    feedItem.Image = Url;
}
```

Than I want to load that images in listview using UrlImageViewHelper by Koush here is the part of code from my FeedItemListAdapter class:

```
var imageView = view.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.ListviewImage);
Koush.UrlImageViewHelper.SetUrlDrawable (imageView, feedItem.Image);
```

I don't get any error but images are not displyed in listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably go and read about [some basic XPath syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp), as your expression doesn't make a lot of sense - it is searching for an element with the name `url` that has a namespace in the namespace manager identified by the prefix `example`.  Does that sound right?

Assuming your element is the root element and it doesn't have a namespace (it's not as to whether you've only given us a snippet), then the expression should be `enclosure/@url`.

Once you've done that, you need to *keep a reference* to the result of your search for that attribute.  At the moment you're just throwing it away and then trying to get the `url` attribute on some arbitrary node in your list.

So, something like:

```
var url = xmlNode[i].SelectSingleNode("enclosure/@url", xmlNameSpaceManager);
feedItem.Image = url.Value;
```

This all said, LINQ to XML is a far nicer API than the old `XmlDocument` API, and LINQ to XML is far nicer to use for querying XML than XPath.  If you can, I would look into that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and advices. Everything else is working good I just had a problem with images. It's little bit old project started couple years ago and I just continue using the same path. Thank you sir.